# Android background service plugin in phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, background-service

I am new to phonegap. i want to create a plugin in phonegap using android background services.
I need continuously calls to that service after every 5 seconds. Please assist me to do so.
Thanks for your attentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using asynchronous task.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav for your reply. I don't get your answer.  
I have used ASynkTask in android but my question was that I want to use android native code for background services as phonegap doesn't provide background services. For this purpose we can use Plugins in Phonegap. So I need few snippets for background services in phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you need but I accomplished something similar by creating a phonegap pluggin that writes data to a static class where I store the information.  Then whenever I need to access it from javascript the plugin simply queries the static class.  Is that what you were trying to accomplish?